# How to create guarded blocks in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

As a user of IntelliJ I would like to protect some piece of a code, so no one can make a change there, even me. I would like to have something like this:

```
class HalfGenerated {

       //[lock]
        .... everything in between of this is not editable.
       //[lock]

}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to lock certain amount of code. But making the whole file "read-only" can be a solution. File->make file read only

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to lock just a portion of the file. I am wondering why JetBrains did not implement this feature there is API for that.